# How to redirect all users to maintainence page except certain IPS through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am new to .htaccess and not able to write conditions in .htaccess as per my need. I have tried many similar solutions shared by other users but still problem is not resolved. So that's why I am putting my issue separately here.

I have a website but for few days, it is going in maintainence mode. For this, I have created maintainence.php file in the root directory. So, if any user hit any url under this domain then they will get message written in maintainence.php file.

But I want to allow some IPs to access whole website, any url under the domain. I am trying to do this thing using .htaccess. And I think doing this with .htaccess file is the best way.

What I have tried is given below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xxx\.xx\.xx\.xx$ #this is IP that I want to allow
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/maintainence.php
   RewriteRule ^(/.*)?$ /maintainence.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The above solution is redirecting everyone to maintainence.php including the mentioned IP.

**Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0):

You are almost deny that IP not allow it , so if you want to allow some IPs and prevent others just fix your code like this :

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xx\.xx\.xx [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xx\.xx\.xx [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xx\.xx\.xx 
 # i just excluded three but you could do less or more 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/maintainence.php
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintainence.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** clear browser cache the test it.